# How do you scroll left and right on a mac?

Tags: osx

in window left and right use Ctrl Wheel, but on mac it just zoom in/out the screen.

Please help

Comment: Try holding SHIFT + ALT and Left clicking with your mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on MAcbook pro with touchpad: hold shift and pan with 2 fingers.

With mouse: hold shift while holding and moving the MMB. Here are the mouse settings I have:

[image]